# How to manage the android application with no access to its source code?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I want to impose certain restrictions on the Android / iOS application while it is running on the device. Eg, I want to restrict copy/paste, apply authentication before this app is instantiated. I do not want to touch the app's source code. How do i do this? Is there a support for this in Android/iOS? I searched a lot, but most of the answers point to App Wrapping service providers. But I want to develop the solution on my own.

Please provide me some help.